# Getting variables from a function in a class in different python file

Tags: python, function, class, oop, variables

I'm trying to get the values of variables from another Python file.
The variables are in a function inside a class.

this is my code with the variables:

```
class Input:

Budget = {'Flexible', 'Variable', 'Fixed'}
Commitment = {'High', 'Medium', 'Low'}

def __init__(self):

    root =Tk()
    root.title('Input window V1')
    root.geometry('1300x690')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    frame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=680)
    frame.configure(background="gray28")
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    header = Label(root, bg="gray28",fg="white", pady=3, text='Please fill the following attributes:', font=("Helvetica", 32))
    header.place(x=240, y=160)


    lbl1 = Label(root, bg="gray28", pady=1, text='Budget:', fg="cyan2" , font=("Helvetica", 20))
    lbl1.place(x=240, y=225)

    lbl2 = Label(root, bg="gray28", pady=1, text='Commitment:', fg="cyan2" , font=("Helvetica", 20))
    lbl2.place(x=240, y=265)

    var1 = StringVar(root)
    pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *Budget )
    pl1.config(width = 20,bg = "GREEN", fg="white")
    pl1.place(x=470, y=230)

    var2 = StringVar(root)
    pl2 = OptionMenu(root, var2, *Commitment)
    pl2.config(width = 20,bg = "GREEN", fg="white")
    pl2.place(x=470, y=270)

    button1 = Button(root, text="GO Hybrid !", command=dashboard)
    button1.config(width=25, bg="white")
    button1.place(x=600, y=590)

    root.mainloop()
```

I wish to get the values of the lists "Budget" and "Commitment" from another python file in the same project.

So i tried:

```
from input import Input

print(Input.Budget)
```

But I get this Error message:
AttributeError: type object 'Input' has no attribute 'Budget'

Thanks! :)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille do you mean: self.Budget = Budget = {'Flexible', 'Variable', 'Fixed'} insted of the Budget row? and to place it above def __init__(self): ? Thanks

Comment: A side note: `input` is a built-in function. Naming your script or module after a built-in function may be a bad idea.

Comment: `Budget` only exists inside the `__init__()` method (for the duration of the `__init__()` method. It is otherwise not part of the `Input` class. Thus you can't access it when using `Input`.

Comment: @00 I will change "input" name thanks

Comment: @User1 Sorry, I pasted and forgot to remove the `self.` part... :/ You have to put `Budget = {...}` in the class body, above `__init__` for example. And, yes, without `self`...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'M getting this error mesage: pl1 = OptionMenu(root, var1, *Budget )
NameError: name 'Budget' is not defined. after placing in above init.

Comment: In the method, you can access it through the instance, as `self.Budget`. I would recommend that you read a tutorial about classes, that would certainly help you a lot by making all of this clearer.